# Why cant i take snapshots in Xamarin Profiler

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

When I start a new session with just the allocation instrument. When it loads it just gets stuck on reading data in the status bar. When I press the snapshot button nothing happens, well the button greys out but it doesn't appear to anything. I can see some errors in the log(attached) but don't know what the cause is.
I have tried on a device and on the simulator. (IOS)

[Screenshot and log file here](https://btcloud.bt.com/web/app/share/invite/MhgmK5oyyi)

Comment: Is your app stopped when you pressed the snapshot button? Snapshots can only be taken when live profiling an app.

Comment: No, it’s running. As I’m using the app, all the instrumentation is being updated but my real problem is I can’t see the live objects as this option is not enabled. I’m guessing that’s related to needing a snapshot first. When I press the snapshot button, it just disables and never comes back. No snapshots are generated.